# Android OutOfMemoryError when retrieving large amount of data

Tags: android, stream, out-of-memory

I have an app that makes a web call and retrieves XML data. The code below works fine if there is not too much data.

```
public class WebClient {

    private static final String TAG = WebClient.class.getSimpleName();
    private String result;


    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        /*
         * To convert the InputStream to String we use the
         * BufferedReader.readLine() method. We iterate until the BufferedReader
         * return null which means there's no more data to read. Each line will
         * appended to a StringBuilder and returned as String.
         */
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }


    public String connect(String url) {
        Log.e(TAG, "inside LoginWebClient.connect(url). url = " + url);

        result = null;

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // Prepare a request object
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);


        // Execute the request
        HttpResponse response;
        try { 
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            // Examine the response status
            Log.i(TAG, response.getStatusLine().toString());





            // Get hold of the response entity
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            // If the response does not enclose an entity, there is no need
            // to worry about connection release

            if (entity != null) {


                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                result = convertStreamToString(instream);
                //Log.i(TAG, result);



                // Closing the input stream will trigger connection release
                instream.close();

            }

                } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.e(TAG, "inside WebClient.connect(url). result = " + result);

         return result;

    }//end of connect
```

.

If the app makes a web call that returns a lot of data, i get a OutOfMemoryError. I've googled the error and it can be caused by holding too much data in memory in the StringBuilder.

As a workaround i have read i can read the Stream straight into a String to avoid the StringBuilder.

i imported the com.google.common.io.CharStreams jar file into my project and tried the following:

```
private static String convertStreamToStringForGetAlerts(InputStream is) {

        String stringFromStream = null;


        try {
            stringFromStream = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stringFromStream;
    }
```

But i still get the following error.

```
06-05 09:44:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(5851): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
06-05 09:44:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(5851): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-05 09:44:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(5851):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
06-05 09:44:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(5851):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
06-05 09:44:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(5851):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
06-05 09:44:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(5851):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
06-05 09:44:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(5851):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-05 09:44:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(5851):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-05 09:44:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(5851):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-05 09:44:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(5851):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-05 09:44:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(5851): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
06-05 09:44:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(5851):     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:94)
06-05 09:44:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(5851):     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:162)
06-05 09:44:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(5851):     at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:311)
06-05 09:44:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(5851):     at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:44)
06-05 09:44:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(5851):     at com.google.common.io.CharStreams.copy(CharStreams.java:204)
06-05 09:44:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(5851):     at com.google.common.io.CharStreams.toStringBuilder(CharStreams.java:245)
06-05 09:44:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(5851):     at com.google.common.io.CharStreams.toString(CharStreams.java:219)
06-05 09:44:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(5851):     at com.carefreegroup.rr3.carefreeoncall.WebClient.convertStreamToStringForGetAlerts(WebClient.java:151)
06-05 09:44:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(5851):     at com.carefreegroup.rr3.carefreeoncall.WebClient.connectForGetAlerts(WebClient.java:198)
06-05 09:44:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(5851):     at com.carefreegroup.rr3.carefreeoncall.WebService.getAlerts(WebService.java:1778)
06-05 09:44:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(5851):     at com.carefreegroup.rr3.carefreeoncall.ShowAlertsActivity$AsyncGetAlerts.doInBackground(ShowAlertsActivity.java:88)
06-05 09:44:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(5851):     at com.carefreegroup.rr3.carefreeoncall.ShowAlertsActivity$AsyncGetAlerts.doInBackground(ShowAlertsActivity.java:1)
06-05 09:44:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(5851):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
06-05 09:44:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(5851):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
06-05 09:44:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(5851):     ... 4 more
```

Has anyone any ideas how i can read this Stream into a String without causing this Error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As a workaround i have read i can read the Stream straight into a String to avoid the StringBuilder.

That doesn't help.  Underneath the covers, the `CharStreams` method is most likely using a `StringBuilder` or equivalent ... and since it cannot know how big the builder needs to be, it will be using the builder's "double-the-size" strategy to expand the backing array.

The most memory efficient way to read data into memory would be to preallocate some kind of buffer (a `StringBuilder`, a `byte[]`, a `char[]`, etc) with a size that is big enough to hold the characters / bytes, and then fill the buffer.  You will still need twice the amount of memory if you need to turn the buffer contents into a String.

But this is only staving off the inevitable scaling problem.  Eventually, the XML will be too big to hold in memory.  What you *really* need to do is to change your code to not try to hold the entire XML document in memory.  You could do one of the following:

- feed it to an event driven XML parser (e.g. SAX) to extract the information of interest, or
- write it to a local file, a byte, character, line or buffer at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in the new InputStreamReader (....)  . why you don't try to apply the byte conversion in the middle of the process.

```
public byte[] read(InputStream istream)
{
   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // Experiment with this value
   int bytesRead;

   while ((bytesRead = istream.read(buffer)) != -1)
   {
      baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
   }

   return baos.toByteArray();
}


// after the process is run, we call this method with the String
public void readLines(byte[] data)
{
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(data)));
  String line;

  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
  {
    // do stuff with line
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't crash now but i cannot get the xml string. All that is returned is the address of the byte[] object eg 06-05 10:47:57.127: E/WebClient(6102): inside WebClient.connect(url)  byteArray.toString() = [B@411bc420

Comment: byte[] bytes = {...}
String str = new String(bytes, "UTF-8"); // for UTF-8 encoding

Comment: I think that way is the proper one...hope to help you!

Comment: sorry i get the OutOfMemory error. i think i might have to write the response to disk.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your data is that large ? what is the size of the XML ?
anyway, You have to cash your data on the disc (preferences, sqlite or file), then read or parse the cached data chunk by chunk.

Answer (score 0):

You can either compress data using a deflater and inflater , or send strings from server in lines using \n and a printwriter , then write the data to a temporary file on the clinet, line by line